# JavaScript constructor not setting correct values

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a simple ES6 class that looks like:

```
class NewsItem {
    constructor(title, date, content, photoURL) {
        this.title = title | '';
        this.date = date | '01-01-00';
        this.content = content | '';
        this.photoURL = photoURL | '../images/image.png';
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble creating instances of the class. Trying something simple like:

```
new NewsItem("fgfdds", "gfdgfd", "fdsfds", "fdsfds");
```

results in a `NewsItem` object, however instead of the passed strings, all of the class' attributes are set to `0`.

[image: Issue]

I'm pretty sure I'm just using JavaScript wrong, but can't figure it out. What's going on here?

Comment: You're looking for `||`, not `|`.

Comment: @AndrewLi that's it. However, I'm not completely sure of the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `|` instead of `||`. The one you're using, [*bitwise* OR](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32), converts the left and right operands to numbers, then applies the operation to those values.

The distinguishing factor is this: **bitwise operations perform operations on the bits**, thus the operands are converted to numbers and the operations are performed on the bits. **Logical operations perform operations logically**, not on the bits themselves, but the data.

Thus:

```
'fgfdds' | ''
```

Is actually using [`ToInt32`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32) internally to convert `'fgfdds'` and `''` to a number. Both come up to be NaN, and the method `ToInt32` returns +0 if the result is NaN. Thus, you're doing this:

```
0 | 0
```

Which is 0 because both operands are 0. Using *logical* OR, or `||`, does not convert the operands to numbers and *logically* evaluates the operands. If one operand or the other is defined or not falsey, then it evaluates to that operand. Thus, try this:

```
this.title = title || '';
```

This will evaluate to `this.title` if `this.title` is defined or truthy, and an empty string otherwise. See [logical operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32) and [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) at MDN.

---

Also, if you're using ECMAScript 2015, try using [default parameters](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32) instead which is a much nicer way to do this:

```
constructor(title = '', date = '01-01-00', content = '', photoURL = '../images/image.png') {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.title = title || '';
```

Assign it like this. [Go here to see the explanation on Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and  [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29)